# Connect 4 on html canvas does not display

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm programming a connect 4 game. Struggling to understand why the page displays for a millisecond and then doesn't show up again. This is despite me calling the setInterval function. The Devtools console doesn't flag any errors so I'm really confused.

I've not included HTML but it is literally just a canvas that include the Javascript code below. This is is the Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){

// Canvas settings
var canvas = document.getElementById("board");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
w = 720;
h = 520;
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

// For the moving piece
// Y position of dropping piece
var y = 55;
// Column x values
var xValues = [60, 160, 260, 360, 460, 560, 660];
var xValuesIndex = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardMove, false);

// Draw board and take keyboard input
function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#007FFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // Row 1 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // Row 2 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // Row 3 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // Row 4 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // Row 5 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // Row 6 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}

function keyboardMove(e){
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            // left key pressed
            if(xValuesIndex==0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                xValuesIndex--;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            // right key pressed
            if(xValuesIndex==6)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                xValuesIndex++;
            }
            break;
        case 32:
            // spacebar pressed
            movingPiece();
            break;
    }
}


function movingPiece(){
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xValues[xValuesIndex], y);
    ctx.arc(xValues[xValuesIndex], y, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    if(y<455)
    {
        y+=5;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 25);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **`ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"`** after drawing all the *arcs*

```js
// Canvas settings
var canvas = document.getElementById("board");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
w = 720;
h = 520;
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;
// For the moving piece
// Y position of dropping piece
var y = 55;
// Column x values
var xValues = [60, 160, 260, 360, 460, 560, 660];
var xValuesIndex = 0;
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardMove, false);
// Draw board and take keyboard input
function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#007FFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    // Row 1 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    // Row 2 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    // Row 3 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 155, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    // Row 4 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 255, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    // Row 5 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 355, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    // Row 6 positions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(160, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(260, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(360, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(460, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(560, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(660, 455, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
 
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; //<-- set this
 
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function keyboardMove(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            // left key pressed
            if (xValuesIndex == 0) {} else {
                xValuesIndex--;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            // right key pressed
            if (xValuesIndex == 6) {} else {
                xValuesIndex++;
            }
            break;
        case 32:
            // spacebar pressed
            movingPiece();
            break;
    }
}

function movingPiece() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xValues[xValuesIndex], y);
    ctx.arc(xValues[xValuesIndex], y, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    if (y < 455) {
        y += 5;
    }
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="board" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

also, **do not** use `setInterval` for canvas animations. use **[`requestanimationframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)** instead.